# How to mock Typescript enums without violating type contract

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a function which accepts an Enum parameter type, for example a function like this.

```
function consumeEnumValue(value: MyEnumType) {
    //do something
}
```

But I don't want to import the real Enum into my test code, I want to use a mocked Enum with fictional entries.  The following doesn't work:

```
import { consumeEnumValue } from 'production-code.ts'

enum FictionalEnum {
    foo,
    bar,
}

describe('consumeEnumValue', () => {
    it('should run and have no type errors', () => {
        expect(consumeEnumValue(FictionalEnum.foo)).toEqual(/* something */);
    });
});
```

Of course typescript complains that the argument type and the parameter type don't match.

Is there a way to mock an enum with fictional values?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the actual enum? It makes no sense to test a function that is supposed to get enum X but in the test will get enum Y

Comment: @NitzanTomer you're absolutely right.  I came to the same conclusion after thinking about it for a couple more minutes.  I posted an answer which explains why I at first thought mocking my enum was a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having thought about the problem a bit more, I don't think my approach in the question makes sense.

In my specific case, the function being tested uses an enum as a set of unique identifiers (protects against mistyping identifiers, alternative to strings in code), but doesn't operate on any particular identifiers.  For example, there's no switch case which produces a result based on the enum value.  Instead it uses the enum value as key to access a map passed as a second parameter.

In general, I don't think it makes sense to unit test with a mocked enum.